# React Navigation 5 nested MapView not expanding to screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a MapView inside a nested Stack Navigator.  In Android the MapView works perfect with the following styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    map: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        zIndex: -1
    },
    customCallout: {
        height: 300,
        width: screenWidth - 25,
    },
});
```

Android shown below:

[image]

However on iOS I get the following:

[image]

I've tried setting the SafeAreaOffsets in my navigator which just pushes my header up underneath the status bar but doesn't change the MapView height at all.  This is an iPhone XR so I want to be able to see the map behind the status bar text for aesthetic purposes.  I am using React Navigation 5.  Before I upgraded, everything worked fine on React Navigation 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be a weird glitch when using React Navigation 5 and `MapView` but I was able to get around the issue by setting the `MApView` style to `postiion: 'absolute'`.